# Two unconnected rings connected by a single atom

Tags: chemfig

How would I draw this hypothetical molecule? All I am able to find is how to draw two rings connected by a common bond, but not how to draw two rings connected only by a single atom. The rotation of the molecule in space is irrelevant.
Thanks for any suggestions.[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably go with something minimalistic as this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{*3(--A([:30]*3(---))-)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or manually: `\chemfig{-[::60]-[::120]A?(-[::0]-[::-120]?)-[::120]}`